# Некорректное выделение памяти для динамического массива

Tags: c, malloc

По заданию необходимо было обработать текст так, чтобы каждое предложение начиналось с большой буквы и не было слов с разрывами при выводе на консоль. Результат требовалось вывести в файл и на консоль. Обработка текста, вроде, у меня получилась. Но при выводе массива с обработанным текстом в файл появляются лишние символы. Видимо, неправильно выделяется память?

На `case 2:` прошу не обращать внимания, там должен быть поиск слов в тексте, но до этого я еще не добрался.

Полный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned search (FILE* file, char *x);
void correction (char *x, unsigned size, unsigned max);

int main()
{
FILE *myfile;
char *text;
unsigned k, size, max;
system("chcp 1251");
system("cls");
printf("Выберите необходимое действие: \n 1) Обработка текста; \n 2) Поиск слова в тексте. \n");
scanf("%d", &k);
switch (k) {
    case 1: myfile = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
            fseek(myfile, 0, SEEK_END);
            size = ftell(myfile);
            rewind(myfile);
            text=(char*) malloc(size);
            max=search(myfile, text);
            fclose(myfile);
            myfile = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
            correction(text, size, max);
            fprintf(myfile, "%s", text);
            fclose(myfile);
            free(text);
            break;
    case 2: myfile = fopen ("output.txt", "r");
}
return 0;
}

unsigned search (FILE* file, char *x) {
unsigned i=0, k=0, max=0;
while ((x[i] = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if ((x[i] != ' ') && (x[i] != '\n'))
        ++k;
    else
        k=0;
    if (k>max)
        max=k;
    ++i;
}
return max;
}

void correction (char *x, unsigned size, unsigned max) {
unsigned k=0, i=0;
if ((x[i]<123) && (x[i]>96))
    printf("%c", x[0]=x[0]-32);
else printf("%c", x[0]);
for (i=1; i<(size-2); ++i) {
    ++k;
    if (x[i-2]=='.' && ((x[i-1]==' ') || (x[i-1]=='\n')) && (x[i]<123) && (x[i]>96))
        printf("%c", x[i]=x[i]-32);
    else
        if ((x[i]==' ') && (k>(120-max))) {
            printf("\n");
            k=0;
        }
        else
            printf("%c", x[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Память выделяется правильно. Просто для обработки вы используете **строки** **заданной** **длинны**  а при выводе в файл функции fprintf(%s) нужна строка **ASCII-z**. А так как у вас **строка** **заданной** **длинны** (max) - то она не будет равна  **ASCII-z** (программа выводит *правильное* значение ASCII-z с точки зрения данной концепции т.е. ваше значение + кусок мусора из памяти до первого нуля). Тогда если вы хотите использовать  fprintf - то 1)или делайте цикл и выводите по символу 2) или добавляете +1 байт к памяти, этот байт в память в correction не передаёте, заполняете его нулём что б было ASCII-z - и будет у вас счастье.

Как простейший пример[1], нужно fprintf(myfile, "%s", text); заменить на

```
for(k=0;k<max;k++) fprintf(myfile, "%c", text[k]);
```

или лучше так

```
fwrite(text,1,max,myfile);
```